# selenium-hub (exit status 137; not expected)

Tags: selenium

I used Selenium Grid Hub and Nodes to collect data, including `selenium/hub: 3.141.59-iron` and `selenium/node-firefox: 3.141.59-iron`, but one day after running, selenium-hub hung the following exception:

> INFO exited: selenium-hub (exit status 137; not expected)

selenium/node-firefox exception is:

> INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to selenium-hub/172.24.0.2:4444

What should I do?